# Managing contents of defaultdict with concurrency in python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, defaultdict

Some questions have looked at non-nested `defaultdict` behavior when multiprocessing:

[Using defaultdict with multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256687/using-defaultdict-with-multiprocessing)

[Python defaultdict behavior possible with multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372007/python-defaultdict-behavior-possible-with-multiprocessing)

and it seems that managing something nested like `defaultdict(list)` isn't an entirely simple process, let alone something more complex like `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`

```
import concurrent.futures
from collections import defaultdict
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, DictProxy, ListProxy
import numpy as np

def called_function1(hey, i, yo):
    yo[i].append(hey)

class EmbeddedManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def func1():
    emanager = EmbeddedManager()
    emanager.register('defaultdict', defaultdict, DictProxy)
    emanager.start()
    ddict = emanager.defaultdict(list)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        for i in range(10):
            ind = np.random.randint(2)
            executor.submit(called_function1, i, ind, ddict)
    for k, v in ddict.items():
        print(k, v)
    emanager.shutdown()
```

trying to register a normal `defaultdict` will fail for the contents inside it, as they aren't being managed, and only the keys are retained:

```
func1()
1 []
0 []
```

a different approach i tried was to add a list within the function, which would be a reasonable compromise

```
def called_function2(hey, i, yo):
    if i not in yo:
        yo[i] = []
    yo[i].append(hey)

def func2():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    ddict = manager.dict()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        for i in range(10):
            ind = np.random.randint(2)
            executor.submit(called_function2, i, ind, ddict)
    for k, v in ddict.items():
        print(k, v)
```

but it still isn't being managed

```
func2()
1 []
0 []
```

I can get this to work by forcing a managed list inside a dictionary before the function is called

```
def called_function3(hey, i, yo):
    yo[i].append(hey)

def func3():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    ddict = manager.dict()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        for i in range(10):
            ind = np.random.randint(2)
            if ind not in ddict:
                ddict[ind] = manager.list()
            executor.submit(called_function2, i, ind, ddict)
    for k, v in ddict.items():
        print(k, v)
```

But I wouldn't prefer this method because i don't necessarily know if I need this dictionary key to even exist before the function is ran

```
func3()
0 [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
1 [1, 5, 7, 9]
```

trying to pass the manager to the function so it can create a managed list on the fly doesn't work

```
def called_function4(hey, i, yo, man):
    if i not in yo:
        yo[i] = man.list()
    yo[i].append(hey)

def func4():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    ddict = manager.dict()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        futures = []
        for i in range(10):
            ind = np.random.randint(2)
            futures.append(executor.submit(called_function2, i, ind, ddict, manager))
        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            print(f.result())
    for k, v in ddict.items():
        print(k, v)
```

```
func4()
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons
```

and trying to create a new manager within the called function

```
def called_function5(hey, i, yo):
    if i not in yo:
        yo[i] = mp.Manager().list()
    yo[i].append(hey)

def func5():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    ddict = manager.dict()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        futures = []
        for i in range(10):
            ind = np.random.randint(2)
            futures.append(executor.submit(called_function5, i, ind, ddict))
        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            print(f.result())
    for k, v in ddict.items():
        print(k, v)
```

raises another error

```
func5()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most straight forward solution is to create a Sync manager and send its address to the children, this way the children can connect to it and request it creates the objects.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np
import threading
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

def called_function2(hey, i, yo, manager_adress, creation_lock):
    manager = SyncManager(address=manager_adress)
    manager.connect()
    if i not in yo:  # to avoid having to enter the lock if the item already exists
        with creation_lock:
            if i not in yo:  # two processes passed the first if on the same key.
                yo[i] = manager.list()
    yo[i].append(hey)

def func2():
    manager = SyncManager()
    manager.start()
    ddict = manager.dict()
    creation_lock = manager.Lock()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        results = []
        for i in range(10):
            ind = np.random.randint(2)
            res = executor.submit(called_function2, i, ind, ddict, manager.address, creation_lock)
            results.append(res)
        for item in results:
            item.result()
    for k, v in ddict.items():
        print(k, v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func2()
```

note that the lock is required to avoid race condition when creating the lists,

**Edit:** a less straightforward way that avoids having to poll the process for the key existance involves a lot of behavior rewriting, so basically you subclass dict to allow you to set the manager address in it, then you override its `__getitem__` to cause it to look up the key or create the object if it doesn't exist .... and since managers are servicing calls with threads you'll need a threadlock to avoid race conditions.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager, DictProxy
import threading

def called_function2(hey, i, yo):
    yo[i].append(hey)

class EmbeddedManager(SyncManager):
    pass

class mydefaultdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, manager_address):
        super().__init__()
        self._threadlock = threading.Lock()
        self._manager_adress = manager_address

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in self:
            return super().__getitem__(item)
        else:
            with self._threadlock:
                if item in self:
                    return super().__getitem__(item)
                manager = EmbeddedManager(address=self._manager_adress)
                manager.connect()
                lst = manager.list()
                super().__setitem__(item, lst)
                return lst

EmbeddedManager.register("defaultdict", mydefaultdict, DictProxy)

def func2():
    manager = EmbeddedManager()
    manager.start()
    ddict = manager.defaultdict(manager.address)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        results = []
        for i in range(10):
            ind = np.random.randint(2)
            res = executor.submit(called_function2, i, ind, ddict)
            results.append(res)
        for item in results:
            item.result()
    for k, v in ddict.items():
        print(k, v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func2()
```

Comment: This has a race condition. Another process could intervene between `if i not in yo` and `yo[i] = manager.list()`.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right, i added a lock to it,